# perl lib issue - not finding lib dir

Tags: perl

For years I have been using the following at the top of my scripts:

```
use lib '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/demo.example.com/cgi-bin/library';
```

That works fine when the lib is within the same domain space as the calling script.

However, I want to call in from a centralised library so I will have just one place to set db credentials.

So, if I adjust that line to call in from another account on the same server, it cannot find the library.

```
use lib '/var/www/vhosts/example2.com/demo.example2.com/cgi-bin/library';
```

Running on plesk, if that may make a difference.  Used to run on cPanel and I had no issue.

I would appreciate a pointer, having already read some docs and I am confused.

Comment: You should not exclude the possibility that each virtual server runs in it's own [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) environment.

Answer (score 2):

Only someone with access to the configuration of your web server can answer this for sure, but I'd guess that each of your vhosts is running as a different user and the users can only read files from their own web space.

This approach won't work. If you want to to have a centralised module library then either install the modules that you want in the system module library (i.e. where `cpan` will install them by default) or create your own new centralised library somewhere that isn't under one of the vhost directories (perhaps under `/opt`).

However, it's worth noting that best practices for deployment of applications are moving in completely the opposite direction. It's generally considered a good idea for each application to have its own set of dependencies installed in its own module library. Using a `cpanfile` to record the exact versions of the dependencies that you're using makes this simple.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the point about best practice and, also, that a one-size-fits-all approach has limitations too. My clients all use the same Db and to manage the credentials for that in one file, would make any changes much simpler to deploy. Pondering more.